# правильно ли составлено предложение с деепричастным оборотом?

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли составлено предложение с деепричастным оборотом? "все мои знакомые восхищаются, наблюдая вблизи мой прекрасный образ"

Answer (score 1):

Если даже не вникать в смысл, то нужна как минимум заглавная и точка.

*Все мои знакомые восхищаются, наблюдая вблизи мой прекрасный образ.*

К самому деепричастному обороту особых претензий нет, но стилистически первое "мои" - лишнее.

Answer (score -1):

Очень даже правильно. А что смущает?